# Hibernate: No CurrentSessionContext configured

Tags: hibernate, liferay

I keep getting a :

> HibernateException: No
>   CurrentSessionContext configured!

in my code.  The only information other searches that returned is that the culprit is:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

in my hibernate.cfg.xml.  I do have that in my hibernate.cfg.xml file, and I am running this in Tomcat 6.  Does anyone know other possible causes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you need to set your current_session_context_class to an actual class...I have my hibernate.cfg.xml configured for that as follows:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

The above code is used for a mySql database but i don't think it matters what type the database is for the above property

Hope this helps

Comment: In @atkeE2036's answer, "hibernate" is misspelled. Here's the correct spelling: <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>`

Comment: @javaloper, it would be nice if you just said that there was a typo: "hibnerate" instead of "hibernate". I was wondering why you posted the same thing in your comment.

Comment: Hibernate 4+ moved this class to: org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext as mentioned by Jacob below

Comment: I was trying to add this line to persistence.xml, but it was actually to hibernate.cfg.xml. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 11):

Both of these work in Hibernate 4+:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

In earlier version of Hibernate it used org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext (as shown in the other answers).

Answer (score 3):

In Hibernate 4.1.5 it is:

```
<property> name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Hibernate 4 on tomcat 7 and the below property (the one mentioned in the question) worked for me.

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = new Configuration().Configure(); // Read config from hibernate.cfg.xml
config.CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>(); // <-- No CurrentSessionContext fixing
return config.BuildSessionFactory();
```