# Hibernate : No CurrentSessionContext configured

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I'm stuck due to some silly mistake somewhere but not able to figure out !

**Hibernate 4.2.6**

I have referred to this question, asked several times previously, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761480/hibernate-no-currentsessioncontext-configured)

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

        <mapping resource="Event.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Event.hbm.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.db.pojo.Event" table="Events">

        <id name="id" column="Id">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="title" column="Title"></property>

        <property name="date" column="Date" type="timestamp"></property>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
package com.db.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder
                .buildServiceRegistry());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Whenever I try this :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at test.EventManager.createAndStoreEvent(EventManager.java:27)
    at test.EventManager.main(EventManager.java:17)
```

**Edited after executing on my personal laptop**

1. The code runs fine if I use 'thread' in the cfg file
2. If I use 'ThreadLocalSessionContext', I get the below exception(**Please note that even the output on the console is now enormous than the previous run**) - is it that the class 'ThreadLocalSessionContext' was not present in the 3.0 version(*I tried to find in the API but the site doesn't have the older API* )

Now I'm suspicious about the dtd - are Hibernate 3.0 jars being referred somewhere while the local ones are ignored, even though SYSTEM is specified? I got the previous exception(no current context) while executing the code on a machine with restricted Internet access. But when I executed the same on my personal laptop :

```
eventDesciption : Team eventDate : 2013-12-12
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: resources/Event.hbm.xml
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Nov 28, 2013 8:55:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Nov 28, 2013 8:56:00 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Nov 28, 2013 8:56:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Nov 28, 2013 8:56:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Nov 28, 2013 8:56:00 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Nov 28, 2013 8:56:00 PM org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl buildCurrentSessionContext
ERROR: HHH000302: Unable to construct current session context [org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext]
org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildCurrentSessionContext(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
    at com.db.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at com.db.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at test.EventManager.createAndStoreEvent(EventManager.java:27)
    at test.EventManager.main(EventManager.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:319)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:149)
    ... 7 more

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at test.EventManager.createAndStoreEvent(EventManager.java:27)
    at test.EventManager.main(EventManager.java:17)
```

Answer (score 65):

As per the best of my knowledge, your configuration is not proper for current session. Instead of

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext</property>
```

use

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

For more information on this, please visit this link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session

Specially, read the last lines of last paragraph.

For those who're using Hibernate 4.1,

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html

Comment: Before posting this question, I had referred to similar posts and  had tried both ways in vain, issue is something else !

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist what exception do you get when you write only `thread` instead of `org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext`?

Comment: I have edited my post - I'm getting different behavior on different machines.

Comment: It is stated in the Hibernate tutorial that "thread" is a value to consider for design and prototype but not for production. So I went to the hibernate library (v4.3) and found that the `org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext` class does not exists. Instead there is a `org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext` class that worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

Try changing

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

to :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Comment: This solves the issue but raises another. If used that way the session must be manually closed to avoid too many open sessions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your property:

**org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext**
to
**Thread**

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone comes here as I did - *this is working*:

```
package com.spring.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static HibernateUtil instance = new HibernateUtil();

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateUtil(){
    this.sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
}

private synchronized static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}

public static HibernateUtil getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
        return new HibernateUtil();
    }
    return instance;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Now to invoke this is quite simple:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory();
```

And the next step would be something like bellow:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(MyObject myObj) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(myObj);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Also make sure that hibernate.cfg.xml is in src/main/resources folder.

Comment: this still has problems. getting the error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

Comment: Ok, don't know what's happening since I can't see the full stack trace but maybe this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281045/why-do-i-get-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-no-currentsessioncontext-configur

Answer (score 2):

For hibernate 4.x you need to use **org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext** instead of 
**org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext** .

However, you can just set the property to **thread** and not ***Thread*** .

> ```
> <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

try changing

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

to :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

What you are trying to do here is that you are trying to get a session.
You can compare this to normal jdbc mysql code where you first create a Connection conn and then you use that conn to create query.

What if you never initialized the Connection conn variable.

The above code is doing that thing.

So to avoid this exception, all you need to do is first open a session using below code.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
```

Once you have used the above piece of code then you can use.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

NOTE:- Avoid using getSessionFactory() as mentioned in some answers since its a depricated method.